# Store an array of hashes in a db Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes from an api that I want to store in a database.  This data is just a list of names that are always going to be the same so I wanted to remove the api call to reduce load times.  How can I store this data?  Do I have to make a model of it?

The data looks like this:

```
[{"id":"30","name":"Mike"},
 {"id":"57","name":"Dave"},
 {"id":"9","name":"Kevin"},
 ....
 {"id":"20","name":"Kyle"}]
```

Would I be able to open a db viewer/editor tool and just type the data in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to be structured in a way that would make it very suitable as a new model in the application. You don't *have* to do that, but for the most conventional storage form, that would be my choice.

Comment: I agree, it would be easy to add a model of it, but I added an edit to the original question: Would I be able to open the db in a db editor and just type the data in?

Comment: Yes, but if this is part of an application that you want to deploy another time then including the data load as part of a migration would probably be better.

Comment: I highly recommend the usage of a Model in this case. The model is flexible, you can add extra methods on the model. Methods like a search function on the name attribute of each hash, for example, or a sorting function, etc...

Comment: @MrYoshiji made it a community wiki if you want to add thoughts in.

Comment: can you post a link to that wiki?  i can't find it but im assuming im just looking in the wrong place